# (Socket Closed) exception in Android when receiving a string from python server

Tags: android, python, tcp

I am trying to communicate between my python server and android client. I setup a connection between them and that works fine, then i send a string to the server from my android app and that works fine as well. The server receives the string and then sends a string in reply to the client but at that time the my code catches an exception. The exception is "Socket Closed" and I've set the `ex.getMessage()` to my textView to see it.
I've set the port number 12345 for it and got a domain ijaw.ddns.net from noip.com which is live.
I've gone through stackover flow many times but cant seem to find the problem. PLease help me with this.

This is my android client code.

package com.example.ozair.ports;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
//Java imports
//import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Button ligar;
    private EditText text1;
    private TextView text2;

    static Socket cSocket;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader in;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        ligar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ligar);
        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);




        ligar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                connect();
            }
        });
    }

    public void connect() {

        cSocket = null;
        out = null;
        in = null;
        dis = null;

        try{
            cSocket = new Socket("ijaw.ddns.net",12345);
            out = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cSocket.getInputStream()));


            final String message = text1.getText().toString();

            out.write(message + "\r");
            out.flush()
            out.close();


            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            int i = in.read(buff);

            in.close();
            out.close();
            cSocket.close();

            text2.setText(buff.toString());

            //cSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            text2.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
//
}
```

And this is my python server code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import time
import threading
import _thread
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)# Create a socket object
s.settimeout(1000)
host = ''        # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def clientthread(c):
     print ('Got connection from', addr)
     threadid=threading.current_thread().name
     print(threadid)
     data = c.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
     #time.sleep(1)
     c.sendall(b'Thank you for connecting')
     #u = unicode(data, "utf-8")
     print("received [%s]" % data)
     c.close()
               #print ("received data: ", data)


s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   _thread.start_new_thread(clientthread,(c,))
   #print 'Got connection from', addr
   #c.send('Thank you for connecting')

c.close()                # Close the connection
sock.close()
```

Comment: For Android: Remove the StrictMode code lines and put your socket/internet code in a normal way in a thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: `out.close();`. Dont do that. It will close the socket too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply BKL.
Without the StrictMode part, my code gives an error when i send a string from my android app to the python server.
And i;ve tried 
in.close();
out.close();
cSocket.close();
in every possible pattern but still the same problem

Comment: That i already told you.